# Check if object is in array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have the code below to check if the object is inside the array, but `in_array()` is always true and I end up with the exact same object inside the array multiple times.

```
if(!in_array($lang, $lang_array, true)){
  $languages .= $lang . ", ";
  $lang_array[] = $lang;
}
```

I end up with something like this:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#389 (1) {
        ["@attributes"]=> array(1) {
            ["Code"]=> string(1) "E"
        }
    }
    [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#388 (1) {
        ["@attributes"]=> array(1) {
            ["Code"]=> string(1) "E"
        }
    }
    [2]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#387 (1) {
        ["@attributes"]=> array(1) {
            ["Code"]=> string(1) "E"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Those `SimpleXMLElement` objects all have different object hashes so they are not the same object.

Comment: @Phil How can I check if the value of the object, in this case "E", is already in an array?

Comment: "E" is not the value of the object.  It is the value of the `Code` index on the `@attributes` property of the `SimpleXMLElement` object.  You would need to loop through each item and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're interested in is the `Code` attribute, why not simply store that then run the array through `array_unique`?

```
$lang_array = [];
foreach(...) {
    $lang_array[] = (string) $lang['Code'];
}
$lang_array = array_unique($lang_array);
$languages = implode(', ', $lang_array);
```

Comment: Hmm.. didn't think of it that way, I just converted the property to string while storing it in the array `$lang_array[] = (string)$lang["Code"];` and now it works :) thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

`in_array` requires an array scan for each call. Better is to make use of string keys. Since the objects are convertible to strings, you can use the string value as keys if the string value is unique. Arrays work well for sets of integers or strings, with the keys as elements, since keys can't be repeated.

```
$langs[(string)$lang] = $lang;
...
$languages = implode(', ', $langs);
```

Comment: Thanks, I did it the other way, the value instead of the key `$lang_array[] = (string)$lang["Code"];`

Comment: @enriqg9: Using it for both would be more performant, as you wouldn't need to use `array_unique()`.